# How to configure Logging without appsetting.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, microsoft-extensions-logging

I am working on .net framework 4.7.2 web API which doesn't have appsetting.json.
I wonder where should I configure the below setting for Microsoft.Extension.Logging?

```json
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
```

and Bind it to LoggerFilterOption on Startup?

Below seems not to work:

```cs
LoggerFilterOptions options = new LoggerFilterOptions();
var config = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
config.GetSection("Logging").Bind(options);
```

I want to control `MinLogLevel` and `Rules` (LoggerFilterOption)through the web.config, Can that be achieved?

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't Microsoft.Extension.Logging part of .NET core, not framework?

Comment: @Neil..yeah but can't we add this package explicitly?...I checked the current LoggerFilterOptions value, MinLogLevel is coming as "Trace" but not sure how to reset it if appsetting.json is not present